# How to write fold_left in CPS?

Tags: algorithm, functional-programming, ocaml, continuation-passing

Even though it's already tail-recursive, It's still interesting to see a CPS version of it.

Here's the standart fold_left:

```
let rec myFoldLeft f acc list =
  match list with
  | [] -> acc
  | h :: tl -> myFoldLeft f (f h acc) tl
;;
```

Here's an example of fold_right

```
let rec myFoldRightCPS f acc list cont =
  match list with
  | [] ->
      cont acc
  | h :: tl ->
      myFoldRightCPS f acc tl (fun t -> cont @@ f t h)
```

I'm using OCaml for this one

Comment: I'm about 30% confident that when you wrote "CPS" in this post, you meant "continuation-passing style". Could you please clarify? Wikipedia lists more than four dozens meanings for this acronym.

Comment: Probably useful: https://discuss.ocaml.org/t/continuation-style-confusioon/10910/3

Answer (score 1):

The function `cps_fold_left` needs to get an accumulator, a folding function, and a function to call with the result of the fold.

Also, the folding functions is also in CPS style, meaning that it accepts an accumulator value, a new value, and a continuation to call to send its result.

As we will see in the implementation, you can even accept two continuations in the folding function: the continuation to call when you want to continue folding, and a continuation to call if you want to stop folding.

For example if you fold a multiplication, the result is zero as soon as you encounter a zero, there is no need to iterate over the rest of the list.

```
let cps_mult a v stop next =
  if a = 0 
  then (stop 0) 
  else (next (a * v))

val cps_mult : int -> int -> (int -> 'a) -> (int -> 'a) -> 'a = <fun>
```

If you call the function with an accumulator that is equal to zero, you call `stop`, otherwise, you call `next`.

If you want to write `cps_fold_left`, you need to remember that you don't call the function recursively, you will call the given `fold` function, for example `cps_mult`, with arguments that are functions to call on completion.

```
let rec cps_fold_left fold acc xs stop =
match xs with
| [] -> stop acc
| x::xs ->
  let next acc = cps_fold_left fold acc xs stop in
  fold acc x stop next
```

You can test is as follows:

```
cps_fold_left cps_mult 1 [3;4] (fun x -> x);;
- : int = 12
```

### Lazy iterators

Having the user-provided folding function be in CPS form itself is useful (e.g. you can short-circuit iteration). Also, notice that the result of `cps_fold_left` is also the result of `fold`, so you can return a value from `fold`, and by doing so you can interrupt the iteration.

Here for example I define a cursor as being either a result (R) or a cursor (C) which is an intermediate result and function of no argument that produces a next cursor.

```
type 'a cursor = R of 'a | C of 'a * (unit -> 'a cursor)
```

I can write `lazy_mult` as follows:

```
let lazy_mult a v _ next = C (a, (fun () -> next (a * v)));;
```

For now I don't care about the `stop` case, but this can be encapsulated in the cursor too.
Then I can call the same `cps_left_fold` function to now have a lazy stream of values:

```
# let cursor = cps_fold_left lazy_mult 1 [2; 3; 4] (fun x -> R x);;
val cursor : int cursor = C (1, <fun>)
```

Thanks to the following `iter` function

```
let iter = function
| R v -> R v
| C (_, f) -> f ();;
val iter : 'a cursor -> 'a cursor = <fun>
```

I can `iter cursor`:

```
# iter cursor;;
- : int cursor = C (2, <fun>)
```

And with that, you can iterate over two lists concurrently, something that is hard to do with plain higher-order functions like `List.fold_left`.

### Remark

> But can you write the version that doesn't require any special operations like `cps_mult`?

Using `cps_fold_left` as define above, it is possible to write a `lift` function that takes a regular operation like `( * )`  and turn it into a CPS style function:

```
let lift f = (fun acc value _stop next -> next @@ f acc value);;
val lift : ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> 'a -> 'b -> 'd -> ('c -> 'e) -> 'e = <fun>

let cps_mult = lift ( * );;
```

Then either you can change `cps_fold_left` so that it calls `lift` itself (and it only accept regular functions), or you let the user call it manually.

The other option I see is to just call `fold acc x`, get a new value, and directly call `cps_fold_left` with the same continuation. That would be identical to `fold_left` except that you eventually call a continuation on the result, and that could be refactored as `cont @@  fold_left fold acc xs`. That doesn't seem useful to me, I mean there is no need to write the function in CPS style in that case.

Or, as in your example, the computation could happen in a fresh continuation, but I don't see a simple way to do that without allocating data to apply the function in the right order.

In your example of `myFoldRightCPS`, a new continuation is created at each level of recursion to make sure that the rightmost element is applied first to the initial accumulator value, and then the result is passed to the previous value, etc. until the function is applied to the first element.

```
let rec myFoldRightCPS f acc list cont =
  match list with
  | [] ->
      cont acc
  | h :: tl ->
      myFoldRightCPS f acc tl (fun t -> cont @@ f t h)
```

This is useful because it makes `myFoldRightCPS` tail-recursive, unlike the direct implementation, and then continuations calling themselves are recursive too, and also tail-recursive. So from that point of view there is an advantage in using the CPS style, which is that the call stack usage is constant w.r.t. input size. The code still allocates data for the intermediate closures, but that's expected.

For the fold left operation, there is no need to delay the computation of the folding operation, and in fact once you delay it you have to reverse the order of operation to obtain the original behavior.

Comment: But can you write the version that doesn't require any special opearions like cps_mult? For example, there is an easy way to convert fold_right to cps and it works just fine with (+), (*) and other operations that are used with regular fold_lelft and fold_right

Comment: If you have an operation like (*) you can easily wrap it automatically to obtain something like cps_mult, in fact cps_fold_left could do the wrapping itself. How do you write `fold_right` to cps? could you give an example of how you would do it by editing your question? that would help understand what you have in mind. Note that the benefit of writing in cps-style is to be able to control the iteration like above, using stop/next; something that the usual fold doesn't allow (except if you allow non-local exits, and even that is not as general).

Comment: Got it, I added an example to my question